# Nginx w/ Passenger support successfully installed - Nginx nowhere to be found

Tags: nginx, passenger

I am deploying a rails app using ubuntu, nginx, & passenger.

I have rails & passenger installed properly. So, I go to run:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

This runs all the way through and tells me it was successful. However, I run nginx -v and it tells me that it is not installed. During Passenger's installation process, I specified it to use /etc/nginx instead of /opt/nginx. I can't continue with my application deployment because the following command won't work (unrecognized service)

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Wondering if anyone has encountered, or understands this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you specified /etc/nginx as prefix then your Nginx is installed in /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx. I think you meant to overwrite the system's Nginx, but that's actually not what you have done: you've only installed a completely seperate Nginx installation, into /etc/nginx. So now you have two instances:

- /usr/sbin/nginx, which uses config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
- /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx, which uses config file /etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Are you on Debian or Ubuntu? If so, then the easiest way to overwrite your system's Nginx with a Phusion Passenger-enabled Nginx is not to use passenger-install-nginx-module, but to use the Debian packages provided by Phusion Passenger.

Comment: I was on Ubuntu. I completely purged Apache and Nginx from the system and reinstalled according to the docs and it fixed it.